# NGINX - Prevent directory traversal attack

Tags: php, security, nginx, permissions

I am configuring my web server by my self first time.

- Ubuntu, NGINX, PHP, SASS etc. installed with latest updates
- Created own user account so i don't have to use root everywhere
- Checked that i don't have unneeded ports open
- Created own folders to every domain
- Every domain runs on own sock on PHP5-fpm pool, with own username

My folder structure is like this:

/var/www/sites/exampledomain1/public/

/var/www/sites/exampledomain2/public/

/var/www/sites/exampledomain2/public/

I made "test.txt" files to every public folder and to /var/, /var/www/. Then i made simple php file that tries to include test.txt files from different places, and i also tried to include /etc/passwd. And it was my "pleasure" to notice that i could include all files in my public PHP file, even /etc/passwd file.

I created "domain" users and put those only to www-data group. Everything but www/.. is untouched so /var/passwd etc is root:root.

/var/www/  755  www-data:www-data

/var/www/sites/  755  www-data:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain1/  711  exampledomain1:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain2/  711  exampledomain2:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain3/ 711 exampledomain3:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain1/public  711  exampledomain1:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain2/public  711  exampledomain2:www-data

/var/www/sites/exampledomain3/public 711 exampledomain3:www-data

At the moment all index.php files are with 701. Owner can read, write and execute, user on same group cant do anything, and public can execute.

My goal is that you cannot include anything from other folders. So if one of my domain has exploit and hacked/cracker can run own code, so it cant include any files from other domains OR from deeper.

Answer (score 3):

To create absolutely isolated environments, you should

a) use Apache backend + suexec + mod_php, because php-fpm does not supports "suexec" as fully as Apache does

b) create not only individual users but also individual groups per your domains

c) configure a couple of name-base virtual hosts, one per domain serviced (hope, you've done already), and set the individual username as suexec parameter

In this case you cat setup 0700 rights to your domain DocumentRoots, and filesystem permissions will definitely separate your domains\users each from other.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I edited php.ini, line "open_basedir", and wrote all okay directories there. Then i added  fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE open_basedir="/var/www/sites/exampledomain1/public"; to every php5-fpm pool server block. I tried my "security test" php file and now it can't include anything that i won't want it to include.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend PHP-FPM and chrooting.   It is fully isolated in ways Apache/suexec could never be and each site has it's own user and it's own chroot.  It's what large ISP/hosting companies use for a reason.

The best part is that PHP-FPM is a breeze with NginX, too.